# Unlink Image from Directory

Tags: php, post, path, file-exists, unlink

i am getting error called 'No such file or directory in' while unlinking the file

here is my code :-

```
$data= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/root_dir/sub_dir/'.$_POST['media'];
  if(unlink($data))){
    echo "sucess";
  }else{
    echo "Faild";
  }
  exit();
```

where in $_POST['media'] is have images/blog/image_name

I am giving absolute path still i am getting this error that is

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/root_dir/follow-to-admin/images/blog/069059b7ef840f0c74a814ec9237b6ec.png
```

please help me out

Comment: Then the file or one of the folders is not there. But the code you show us does nothing like trying to delete a file??

Comment: Showing us nonsense code does not help our ability to help you

Comment: sorry sir i have remove that unlink function for something and forgot to add back ihave updated the code please check

Comment: Do a `dir C:\xampp\htdocs\root_dir\follow-to-admin\images\blog\069059b7ef840f0c74a814ec9237b6ec.png` from command line. Then show us the output

Comment: This is what it returns Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is D04F-A81E

 Directory of C:\xampp\htdocs\root-di\follow-to-admin\images\blog

23-10-2020  03:08 PM           272,494 069059b7ef840f0c74a814ec9237b6ec.png
               1 File(s)        272,494 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  44,319,281,152 bytes free

Comment: So file seems to be there. Hmmmm

Comment: Yes Sir and suppose i wright code link
$data= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/root_dir/follow-to-admin/images/blog/069059b7ef840f0c74a814ec9237b6ec.png';

unlink($data) 

then it's working fine